# ij.getVersion() is 2.5.0/Inactive

Tags: python, imagej

I want to use imagej packages on jupyter notebook. I successfully made the required installations but when I run

```
ij.getVersion()
```

I get 2.5.0/Inactive and consequently cannot proceed. Could you help?

Comment: Questions about ImageJ and pyimagej are best asked on https://forum.image.sc

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue here, and I've found that if there is an error in your notebook at any point imageJ enters into its "Inactive" state. The fix for me seems to be restarting the kernel each time this error occurs.